# Why clamav result is not showing all files/sub-files/subdirectories count

Tags: 14.04, clamav

Here is my result:

```
Known viruses: 6375266
Engine version: 0.99.2
Scanned directories: 7
Scanned files: 9
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 119.98 MB
Data read: 36.17 MB (ratio 3.32:1)
```

Command I ran:

```
 clamscan --recursive --infected --log=/home/ubuntu/temp.log --include-dir='^\/var\/lib\/tomcat[7]\/webapps' --quiet /* 2>/dev/null
```

It's not showing all files count but only current directory and its files count.

Comment: I also ran using sudo access, if clam is not accessing any files it will show errors but here it is not showing actual files count with or without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "sudo" in front of the command.

No "sudo" no access to files that that user does not own. And clamav is likely to silently ignore those files.